# When calling the unwind method of a View Controller, the sourceViewController of the segue passed along is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I want to unwind from a normal `UITableViewController` Toolbar (a Save Button), which I connected to the Exit icon indicating my unwind method which does something like this:

```
    -(IBAction)saveItem:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender
     {
       MyTableViewController * sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController;
       NSNumber * someNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: sourceViewController.targetNumber];
      ...
     }
```

The problem is that for some reason, when I call `sender.sourceViewController`, it yields `nil`. Any ideas on this? After reading through Apple's examples and some tuts on the net, I still get a crash once I try to do anything with the source view controller. Yet the IBAction is precisely the place where the source view controller should not yet have been destroyed.

Can anybody help here?
Thanks! Will greatly appreciate.

Comment: I've never seen this problem with unwind segues before, so I'm guessing that you have something set up wrong, but it's hard to say what. Can you upload the app somewhere that we could look at it?